# como puedo formatear la fecha de mi input type="week" en español?

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, input-type

Buenos Días el caso es que tengo un calendario por semana al guardar y enviar el valor
ej : semana 20 me lo envia asi :

requestDate: "2021-W20" como puedo hacer para formatear esa fecha en español y no en ingles ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hola te dejo una buena opción para poder poder formatear la fecha con **toLocaleDateString**

```js
function exe(ele,e){
  console.log(getDateRangeOfWeek(ele.valueAsDate))
}
function getDateRangeOfWeek(dateini){
    const options = { weekday: 'long', year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: 'numeric' };
    datefin=new Date(dateini);
    datefin.setDate(datefin.getDate()+7)
    return dateini.toLocaleDateString("es-MX",options) + " a " + datefin.toLocaleDateString("es-MX",options);
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="week" name="semana" onchange="exe(this,event)"/>
</body>
```

Comment: oh , genial gracias , me sirve de guia para aplicarlo a mi caso , saludos

Comment: porfa @MatiasArturoGonzálezRoa puedes colocar la respuesta como aceptada